# Kendo UI tabstrip - delay in displaying the tab when swtiching

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI tabstrip with 3 tabs with Kendo Grids all 3 tabs without paging. my tab 3 (say tab3) has a kendo grid that has more than 10000 records, it takes a while for data to load, that's ok and undertandtable but the problem is that if I switch between tab2 and tab3 when I come back to tab3 since it has to load 10000 rows the screen freezes and loads tab3 in a few seconds and only then tab3 gets displayed. However when I scroll down the grid in tab3 and then switch the tabs all works fine. My question is why does it take time to display tab3 while swtiching the tabs since the grid in tab3 was already loaded in the first time, and I don't think the data bound happens while switching the tabs, so why is taking time to display tab3 when do not touch the scroller of the grid in tab3 or else it all works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would strongly suggestion reading through this article on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updating your question to meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code, it's really hard to figure out exactly what your problem is. A potential fix though is to add virtual paging to the third grid. Simply add the attribute

```
.Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true)
```

to your grid and

```
.PageSize(500)
```

to your DataSource. You can replace the pagesize with whatever amount of records you want to load at a time. It should increase the performance of changing tabs considerably, and unlike traditional paging, it doesn't make navigation of the grid slower, as it automatically loads more data as you scroll down.

Note: The code I wrote is for asp.net MVC Razor syntax. Since you didn't specify which version of Kendo you're using, [HERE](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/virtualization-remote-data) is a link to the demo project on the telerik website, where you can select whichever version you're using to see how to implement it.